# UML, use-case realization

Tags: uml, use-case

I’m trying to prepare UML model for my project. It’s quite complex however I focus on one of use-case. In short term, use case name is “Edit patient results” and actor “Doctor” uses it. In fact, entering results triggers always the set of following actions:

- List item
- Normal Ranges calculation
- Related Expression calculation
- Interpretation merging

Assuming that I have my use-case diagram prepared as follows:
[image: main use-case]

My questions are:

1. How shall I draw actions that are triggered automatically? As  extended use-cases like this?
   [image: extended use-case]
2. How shall I draw “Edit patient results” use-case realization? Each edit operation involves several software components interactions, shall I use collaboration diagrams? (how to join my main use-case with them), maybe something else?
3. How to draw sequence diagrams to show actions sequence and parameters passed? How to join these diagrams with my use-case.
4. What is the best way to show use-case realization

I'm using Enterprice Architect.
Thank You !!!

Answer (score 3):

1. No. These are just activities which are part of scenarios inside the use case. Trying to make the use cases is functional analysis the wrong way. A use case synthesizes a number of steps under a common goal/added value.
2. A use case realization is a collaboration (bubble with dashed line border; along with the UC in the toolbox). The collaboration contains diagrams which show how the single classes communicate/collaborate to realize (parts of) the use case. Use a Realization from Collaboration to Use Case.
3. Put the SDs inside the collaboration and group/name them reasonably.
4. see above

As to your comments:

- Edited 2.
- I never found a good use for Collaboration Use and I've done a lot of successful UC modeling. So you can probably live without it as well.
- Put Actions inside an Activity representing a scenario and connect them as desired. You might look into BPMN as well.

Comment: Thanks!!! So how shall I join my use-case "Edit Patient Result" with related collaboration? Shall I use Collaboration Use?

Comment: Also? How can I show in UML that "Enter Patient Results" use-case triggers several steps? Which diagrams/elements shall I use?